# NullPointerException in DOM seletor method

Tags: android, jsoup

I keep getting this error

NullPointer

```
08-16 22:55:46.360: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11047): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  08-16 22:55:46.360: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11047):     at com.fttech.htmlParser.releaseInfo.onCreate(releaseInfo.java:62)
08-16 22:55:46.360: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11047):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
08-16 22:55:46.360: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
```

Its pointing to my Element here

```
    Element paragraph = overview.select("p").last();
```

i am using this to retrieve the article

```
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    if(doc == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Couldnt retrieve game info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    else{

    // Get the overview div
    Element overview = doc.select("div#object-overview").last();
```

Comment: overview may be null or overview.select("p") may be null. is that possible you to log html string and see?

Comment: I logged them for some it works PERFECT but for example http://pc.gamespy.com/pc/robot-entertainment-project-1-untitled/ this link gives a error at // Element overview = doc.select("div#object-overview").last();
When i try and log it.

Comment: Also this link too http://xbox360.gamespy.com/xbox-360/street-fighter-iii-third-strike-online-edition/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you look for an element with select("") your calling last() in a chain which assumes it will **always** find atleast 1 element, in the situation that there is no say "p" in the document, that is when you will encounter a crash.

It's just simple NullPointerExceptions, you need to learn to code defensively:

```
// If you believe overview could be null
if(overview != null){
    ArrayList<Element> paragraphs = overview.select("p"); // Whatever type select(String) returns
    Element lastParagraph = null;
    if(paragraphs != null){
         lastParagraph = paragraphs.last();
    } else {
     // Deal with not finding "p" (lastParagraph is null in this situation)
    }

   // Continue with lastParagraph 

} else {
  // Deal with overview being null
}
```

[Number 1 Java Error](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html) (scroll down)

Also you shouldn't really wrap your code with a catch all Exception, try to catch each exception and deal with them individually.

Lookup the API for your get() method [Jsoup get()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#get%28%29) (eclipse tells you this anyway) It throws IOException, so you should *just* catch this.

```
  try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Tag", "Jsoup get didn't get a document", e);
    }
```

[Number 5 Java Error](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html) (scroll down)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this in a few and mark your answer correct when I do. Also thanks for the link. Its helpful. And also what and how should I be cstching for these and which exceptions?

Comment: I was forgetting to log the error in the catch. how could I loop the try to loop till it gets it? or this may be uneccessary, either it wasn't fetchd because of bad service or a server is down.

Comment: Number 5 in that link I showed you is about your catch block :-). Yes if it wasn't fetched either inform the user with a message and a retry button, or use a while(doc==null && retry<5) or similar loop.